# Which statistical test for data comparison?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, biostatistics, genetics

I have several sets (e.g. 100) of essential genes + non-essential ones, all were extracted from a certain database of essential genes for a particular disease under different conditions. How can I compare these sets to check if the results obtained under different conditions (100) are significant?

For instance, set #1 contains 2000 genes containing 100 essential genes (found in the hypothetical database) + 1900 non-essential genes, and so forth. It should be noted that the hypothetical database "only" contains essential genes (from which essential ones in each dataset/subset were taken).